# PowerBI remember filters when opening new report from another report

Tags: powerbi, visualization, reporting, dashboard, business-intelligence

We are building a new dataplatform. In this platform we want to create multiple new dashboards. The first few dashboards have aggregated information; the other reports contain all the details.

The structure is as follows:

- report 1 has aggregated information
- report 1a has all the details concerning the data in report 1

Report 1 is placed in workspace A, report 1a is placed in workspace B.

Currently we are able to click on the number and that it opens report 1a in another tab; however it does not remember the filters we used in report 1.

Now we want to have the following function:
When i click on a number in report 1, i want powerbi to open report 1a in a new tab but remembering the filters i used in report 1.

Are there any solutions for this inconvenience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. If both reports are in the same workspace or app, then you can use [Use cross-report drillthrough in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-cross-report-drill-through).
2. If reports are in different workspaces, then you can look at using URL Filtering [Filter a report using query string parameters in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters). This option will offer the most flexibility but will require a little more work and maintenance.

For option 2 - You would create a Measure and ensure its `Data category` is set to `Web URL`. The measure will need to check and see which filters/slicers are set, and then build the URL with the filters. For example:

```
// set this to the URL of the report WITHOUT any URL filters
Link report 1a base = "https://....."

Link report = 
  IF ( ISFILTERED(slicerTable[slicerColumn]),

    [Link report 1a base] & 
    "&$filter=Table/Column in ('" &
    CONCATENATEX( DISTINCT(slicerTable[slicerColumn]), [slicerColumn], "','") &
    "')"

    ,

    [Link report 1a base]
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried this second option and as a result i do get the right URL. However once clicking on the URL, it does open report 1a, but does not include the filters I have chosen in report 1. I made sure the data category is set to a web URL and am working with the same column in both reports, which contains simple string options to filter with.  I do see the filters active in the URL. Do you have any idea why the filters do not get applied in report 1a?

Comment: There are a few special characters that need to be handled - see [
Special characters in URL filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-url-filters). Could you share an example of what Url filter query looks like?

Comment: Currently I am testing it on my ''discipline' filter which is a column in my 'cost centre' table. The table 'cost centre' is one table that is used in both report 1 and report 1a. In the future i would like to adapt this to be able to use hierarchy filtering, but for now i would like to get this to work haha. (sorry  cannot get the formatting to work)

`Link = IF(ISFILTERED(costcentre[discipline]),[link base] & "&$filter=costcentre/disciplinein (" & CONCATENATEX( DISTINCT(costcentre[discipline]), [Discipline], ",")&")", [link base])
`

Comment: Ah, each bit needs to be in single quotes like `in ('Milk', 'Cheese')`. Try `in ('"&                                 CONCATENATEX( DISTINCT(Costcentre[discipline ]), [discipline], "','") & "')"`

Comment: ah yes that already gets me closer! Now when I click on the link it opens report 1a and the only options in my discipline filter are the ones I chose in report 1 . Is it also possible to get them selected? I can understand that it might be confusing for the end-user to not see it selected.

Comment: Unfortunately no, URL Filtering is the same as applying filters at the report level in the right filter pane.

Comment: ah allright, thanks for your quick response. Do you happen to know if it is possible to use this URL principle with hierarchy filters?

Comment: Should be possible, you'd have to send each selected level of the hierarchy in the URL.